# How to make a String From 2 others in one line?

Tags: java, android, string, textview, append

I have in my app activity two textviews one with date("yyyy-mm-dd ") and one with time("hh:mm")

How can i make a string that combines these textviews together so my String will be (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) so that i can sort datetime text values in my sqlite database.

code for date textview:

```
String date = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTV))
            .getText().toString();
```

code for time textview:

```
String time= ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTV))
            .getText().toString();
```

How to make String datetime tha combines them in one line/fast?

Comment: Use concatenation. String combine=date+time;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate with a plus-sign

```
  String datetime = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTV)).getText().toString() + ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTV)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String date = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTV)).getText().toString();
String time = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTV)).getText().toString();

String combined = date + " " + time;
```

Lookup string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

```
new StringBuilder().append(date).append(" ").append(time).toString();
```

This, in theory, faster/better than concatenating strings with +. Although you won't see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this**

```
 String date = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTV))
        .getText().toString();

 String time= ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTV))
        .getText().toString();

String datetime = date.concat(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use [Calendar.set()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

```
 public final void set(int year,
                  int month,
                  int date,
                  int hourOfDay,
                  int minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateAndTime = date + time;
```

Is it really this you wan't?

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation

```
String newDate = date + " " + time;
```

Comment: Lol, the answers are flooding. You will have a hard time choosing the best answer.